# Python: Count occurrences of each number in a python data-frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-mining

I have a dataset for itemset mining. I want to find occurences of each unique number i.e. Candidate 1 itemsets.

The shape of the data is 3000x1. I'm unable to figure out how to count the unique occurences.

List of distict values of the data are stored.

Using the ndarray distinct, how can I find the frequency of each item in the dataset?

**Update**
Got the solution with @jojo help.

```
df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv', sep=',')
all_values = dataset.values.ravel()
notNan = np.logical_not(np.isnan(all_values))
distinct, counts = np.unique(all_values[notNan], return_counts=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that if you have a normal csv (comma separated) you should use `sep=','`. This is because `'\t'` is assuming TAB as delimiter.

Also, consider adding `header=None` in your `read_csv` call, as otherwise the first line will be taken as column names in your data-frame.

Lastly, since the column appear to have different lengths, you will have `nan` values in all columns that are shorter than the longest one, to remove them you can mask all `nan` values when getting unique values. Something like `values[np.logical_not(np.isnan(values))]`, but see below.

---

Putting things together:

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv', sep=',', header=None)

all_values = dataset.values.ravel()
```

You can directly use [`unique` from numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html#numpy.unique) which allows to get the counts of each unique value:

```
import numpy as np
notNan = np.logical_not(np.isnan(all_values))
distinct, counts = np.unique(all_values[notNan], return_counts=True)
```

If you care for the frequency, simply divide `counts` by `all_values[notNan].size`.

---

Here is a simple example (from the docs linked above) to highlight how `np.unique` works:

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([1, 2, 6, 4, 2, 3, 2])
>>> values, counts = np.unique(a, return_counts=True)
>>> values  # list of all unique values in a
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 6])
>>> counts  # count of the occurrences of each value in values
array([1, 3, 1, 1, 1])
```

Comment: Thanks, I updated my code as per your suggestion. Kindly have a look at Update 1 I made to my post. Can you please explain the output a bit?  The distinct array is counting some numbers but those are certaininly not unique values as they are repeating. Right? Also the counts array is all 1. Please elaborate on this.

Comment: Thanks. But as you can see, event the distint is returning the array which has like multiple 0s and 10s etc. So this isn't actually unique. What could be the reason here? Please note that my dataset is 3000x1. I also added an excel screenshot to make visualizing clear.

Comment: Yes exactly. I want to deal with them seperately. I updated the code but getting an error. Kindly refer to update-2.

Comment: I want to get unique values in the entire csv. For example count occurence of item 23 in entire dataset and so on for every unique itemset.

Comment: Ultimately I want to return a table with two columns. The first one is the unique item-set value and the next column containing the total occurences of that itemset in entire csv. There is no specific reason to choose pandas, I can free to use other data-loaders as well.

Comment: Ok, made an update. Let me know if it works. Also, let's clean up the comment section a little.

Comment: Thanks. With your suggestion and by adding a header to the dataset (It was giving the error: Expected 10 rows find 14 at line 4 otherwise), I was able to get the unique values and their respective counts. Thanks